# How to convert related products section to custom tab in products detail page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to convert related products section to custom tab in products detail page in magento 2

Comment: Can u please check with uloaded answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one,

put this code on app/design/frontend/vendor/your theme/view/frontend/catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <!-- Create new tab-->
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custominfo" template="Magento_Catalog::product/related-products.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Related Products</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

<!-- Move the content-->
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.details" />
```

Call the function in phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `catalog_product_view.xml` file under:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and use the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>

       <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related.custom.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Related Products(Put your custom tab title here)</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this will help you!